# SQL request process with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I would like to add  in a  with JS from a JSP variable that contains the result of a SQL query.

This is my two inputs :

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Code postal* :</label></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="cp" placeholder="CP du lieu de résidence" required /></td>
    <td><label>Ville* :</label></td>
    <td><select name="ville" required disabled/></select></td>
</tr>
```

And ths is my JS and JSTL query:

```
<sql:query dataSource="jdbc/Referentiel" var="communeCp" > 
    SELECT code_postal, nom_commune_min, insee_commune FROM  commune
</sql:query>
<script>
    $('input[name=cp]').keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 5) 
        {   
            $('select[name=ville]').prop('disabled', false);
            var communeListe = "${communeCp}";
            for (var i in communeListe)
            {
                var currentCp = communeListe[i][code_postal];
                var currentVille = communeListe[i][nom_commune_min];
                if($('input[name=cp]').val() == currentCp)
                { 
                    $('select[name=ville]').append('<option value="'+ currentVille +'">'+ currentVille +'</option>');
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $('select[name=ville]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

My navigator say "code_postal is not defined".

I am forced to use ajax to do this ? I really don't know ajax. :/

Comment: Dude there's nothing to "know" about ajax :) It's not a language or a framework. It's just calling an external document, and when the response comes back, do something with it. End of story! See api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax - Write your SQL query in a PHP file, call it from your JS, that's just what ajax is.

Comment: I found the real probleme, it is just how can I affect the query response in my var communeCP to my JS variable.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea :) Never used JSP/JSTL. I was just passing by to tell you about ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"code_postal is not defined" happens because of this line of javascript:

```
var currentCp = communeListe[i][code_postal];
```

Javascript thinks code_postal is the name of a variable, but there's no "var codePostal = ..." anywhere in your javascript.

**Here's what's going on with your JSP page:**

First, your JSP is rendered. JSP invokes the SQL query and stores the result in the communeCp variable (an object of type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result).

JSP then replaces this line:

```
var communeListe = "${communeCp}";
```

with the result of evaluating "communeCp.toString()". I don't know what that is, but it might be something as simple as the default Object.toString implementation, so this is the actual javascript that would be rendered to the page:

```
var communeListe = "javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.Result@123456".
```

Now that the JSP has been rendered, the browser executes the javascript. It fails to even evaluate because you have the undefined code_postal reference, but if for some reason that wasn't a problem, it would fail because you are trying to do a for each loop over the communeListe, but javascript sees that communeListe is just a simple string, so it doesn't make sense to do a for loop over that.

**Now, with that understood, I'll try to explain how you could achieve the behavior you want without AJAX.**

From your code, it looks like you want the following behavior: A user needs to enter a postal code and select a ville in that postal code. After they've entered 5 characters of their postal code, enable the "ville" dropdown and populate it with the possible villa choices for that postal code.

You have the basic idea for one way to achieve this: Do a query in JSP that gets all postal codes and all villes, then, when the postal code is entered, look through this data somehow in javascript and populate the ville dropdown with the villes that are in that postal code.

The problem is in making the data from the SQL query available to the javascript. Here's how you might do that without AJAX. The basic idea is to initialize a javascript array of objects using a literal which is generated by rendering your JSP:

```
<sql:query dataSource="jdbc/Referentiel" var="communeCp" > 
    SELECT code_postal, nom_commune_min, insee_commune FROM  commune
</sql:query>
<script>
    var communeListe= [];
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${communeCp.rows}">
        communeListe.push({
            code_postal: '${row.code_postal}',
            nom_commune_min: '${row.nom_commune_min}',
            insee_commune: '${row.insee_commune}'
        });
    </c:forEach>
    $('input[name=cp]').keyup(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 5) 
        {   
            $('select[name=ville]').prop('disabled', false);
            $.each(communeListe, function(index, currentRow) {
                var currentCp = currentRow.code_postal;
                var currentVille = currentRow.nom_commune_min;
                if($('input[name=cp]').val() == currentCp)
                { 
                    $('select[name=ville]').append('<option value="'+ currentVille +'">'+ currentVille +'</option>');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('select[name=ville]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Be warned!** This has the potential to make the page very slow to load if you have a lot of rows in the commune table, because you are sending the text of every single row to the user's browser.

**For you use case, it would almost certainly be a better overall design to use AJAX**. The way this would improve load speeds is that it would only query for the villes that it needs and it would only need to send back a small subset of all possible villes to the user's browser. I can provide a bit of guidance on that:

Basically, you will first need to develop a server-side webservice. You can probably just make this using a Java servlet since you are already using JSP. This servlet will need to accept a postal code as a request parameter and will do a query to the commune database on that postal code (so it should only get rows where postal_code == the postal code request parameter value). It will then return JSON containing an array of objects representing those rows from the commune database, so something like this:

```
//assume this is the request coming to your webservice
/get_villes?postalCode=12345

//This would be the JSON response returned by your webservice
[
    {
        'nom_commune_min': 'ville name 1',
        'insee_commune': 'insee_commune 1'
    },
    {
        'nom_commune_min': 'ville name 2',
        'insee_commune': 'insee_commune 3'
    },
    ... and so on depending on how many villes have that postal code
]
```

To implement this webservice you could make a simple java object called something like Commune and give it nom_commune_min and insee_commune as fields. Then you could use a simple JSON serialization library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to serialize that object to a string and return that from your servlet as the body of your HTTP response.

On the frontend side, you'll need to change your javascript so that, when the postal code is entered, it uses $.ajax({ ... }) and invokes that webservice, you made passing it the value of the postal code to lookup.

The call to $.ajax might look something like this (I would probably use $.get just because it's a simpler version of $.ajax):

```
$.get({
    url: "/get_villes?postalCode=" + postalCode,
    success: function(communeCp){
        $.forEach(communeCp,function(index,currentRow){
            //put code here to populate the dropdown list using
            //currentRow.postal_code, just like the previous code I provided                
        });
    },
});
```

Another thing to consider is that, since this is asynchronous, when the browser performs this query, the dropdown is going to be blank for a small time while that query runs (but the user will still be free to interact with the page and might be confused by the blank enabled ville dropdown). So, you need to communicate to the user that you are waiting for results from the webservice when that javascript ajax query runs. So, you could do something like show a "Loading..." text somewhere when they enter the 5 digits of their postal code, and then hide that text in the success function of that $.get (after the dropdown is populated).

Other than that, I would suggest you take some time to wrap your mind around how AJAX and webservices work and look at some tutorials and examples. Webservices, ajax, and everything related to building dynamic websites are a vital part of modern web development.

Comment: Oh My God ! Thank you very very very much for that perfectly complet aswer.
I juste need to replace simple quote by double quote in the .push().

It is the first time i use java script and i don't have time to learn ajax now, but it is effectively very interesting.